# Unable to Allocate Memory

Tags: c, memory, malloc

I am unable to allocate memory using the following code:

```
int *h_VC = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*SIZE); //SIZE is 19200
if(h_VC==NULL)
{
 printf("Memory Not avaialble");
}
```

My code uses the above block in a while loop and is run several times. 
I have 8GB memory. I am monitoring the free memory at the same time when running the code.
The memory allocation is failing although i have arround 3GB of free memory left.
What could be the problem?

Comment: I assume you're using a 64 bit OS?

Comment: Just a note: don't cast the returned pointer of `malloc`. Theres no need to and it is possibly dangerous.

Comment: Don't know if this is the case, but it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: I test it,and it works fairly

Comment: can you offer more details? OS, compiler, etc?

Comment: If it's a 32-bit program running in a 64-bit OS, you can still have plenty of free memory in the OS, but exhausted address space in the program due to memory fragmentation or leaks or just too many too big allocations. Which one it is it's hard to tell without any additional information about the program and OS.

Comment: Perhaps you're running into `ulimit -v`?

Comment: @arncore: First, you don't have to cast a `void*` to a specific pointer type. This happens automatically and does not invoke any compiler warnings as it is mandated by the standard. It might be dangerous because you might link to another function with the name `malloc` but another return type and would not even notice, since you are explicitly casting. This would also not invoke any warnings since the compiler would assume you know what you are doing. Avoid explicit casts, unless necessary is a good rule of thumb.

Comment: @Alex: agreed. If it's 32 bit, and really 5GB allocated, then the OS deals with a "-1GB" linear address space situation, and must be swapping like crazy to handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Visual Studio as a compiler. Compiling the program as x64 solved the issue.
thanks to Alex's comment.

Answer (score 5):

Anything could be the problem. Replace the `printf` with

```
perror("");
```

to get a hint.

Comment: Except beer... Beer is never the problem... +1

Comment: *Beer is the cause and the solution to all problems in life.* - Homer J. Simpson